# Revaluate components of the Home after Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React-router-dom in my application, there is a form in the home (http://localhost/).

After I do the action, which is created at my page Home.tsx, I need to update the list but the Redirect isn't working as it is the same page, so I'm out of ideas.

I have seen there is an init option in Redirect but it doesn't seem to help me or at least I couldn't find it.

Here is the code of Home.tsx

```
import Measuraments from '@components/Measuraments/Measuraments'
import NewMeasurament from '@components/Measuraments/NewMeasurament'
import Wines from '@models/wines.model'
import { getAuthToken } from '@util/auth'
import getCurrentHost from '@util/host'
import { json, redirect, useNavigation } from 'react-router-dom'


export const Home = () => {

  return <>
          <NewMeasurament /> //Form
          <Measuraments />   //The component I need to render again
        </>
}

export default Home

export const action = async ( { request } ) => {
  const data = await request.formData()
  const measuramentData: Wines = {
    // Stuff
  }

  const currentHost = getCurrentHost()

  const token = getAuthToken()

  const response = await fetch( currentHost + 'measuraments', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(measuramentData)
  })

  return redirect('/')

}
```

Router inside App.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: tokenLoader,
    id: 'root',
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />,
        loader: checkAuthLoader,
        action: AddMeasureAction
      },
      { 
        path: '/login', 
        element: <LoginPage />,
        action: AuthAction,
      },
      { 
        path: '/logout', 
        action: LogoutAction
      }
    ],
  }
])
```

Comment: Where did you involve `action` function? I can't see. And the purpose of this question is to redirect to special path outside of component?

Comment: @VictorL. I added the router I'm using, as far as I understood, the Form will call the action of the nearest path if it isn't specified, that part works but I want to refresh the Measuraments components or the HomePage because it fetch data from the database where the form adds the info